# CSS and HTML file is not working at Git Hub

Tags: html, css, github, github-pages

I have separated some HTML files other than index.html and CSS too. It is working well in VS code but on creating Git Hub pages only index.html file is running.
Here is my repository:- https://github.com/shashi-singh18/BlogWritingSite
please help!

Answer (score 0):

Change you links to the following structure

```
src='./css/utils.css'
```

Your current paths force your index.html to search for a sub-directory "BlogWritingSite" which does not exist at that reference level.

Comment: thanks all css file is working well but still other html file is not working like -blogpost.html
contact.html
search.html <https://shashi-singh18.github.io/BlogWritingSite/>

Comment: Apologies for the delay. You'll want to add a ./ before the file name when accessing things i your current directory e.g. src='./contact.html'

Answer (score 0):

I saw your repository and noticed some errors when linking your css file in index.html

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/BlogWritingSite/css/utils.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/BlogWritingSite/css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/BlogWritingSite/css/mobile.css">
```

change for

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/utils.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/mobile.css">
```

and

change the name of your css folder to lowercase letters

after

```
CSS
```

fixer

```
css
```

Comment: thanks all css file is working well but still other html file is not working like -blogpost.html contact.html search.html   <https://shashi-singh18.github.io/BlogWritingSite/>

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I think the error is in the address of the CSS files
Here, you should have given the address of each CSS file, relative to the `index.html` file and not the project directory as a whole

Try changing these `link` tags to this and tell me if it works.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./CSS/utils.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./CSS/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./CSS/mobile.css">
```

Comment: thanks all css file is working well but still other html file is not working like -blogpost.html contact.html search.html <https://shashi-singh18.github.io/BlogWritingSite/>